# 'Forward, Warsaw!' in Latin?

Tags: english-to-latin-translation

How would you translate 'Forward, Warsaw!'into Latin.

'Varsovia' appears to be the accepted Latin name for the city. But I can't seem to find an adequate term for 'forward'.

Background: a 1905 Polish revolutionary song features the demand "naprzód Warszawo" in the chorus - literally "forward, Warsaw" (meaning 'march ahead, Warsaw' or 'push ahead, Warsaw').

What is the Latin equivalent - there must be something along the lines of "forward, legions" in Roman literature?

Many thanks.

Comment: I suppose the Italian translation would be "avanti Varsovia", so maybe the Latin version is something similar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest: ***Porro, Varsovia!***

The adverb [*porro*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=porro&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059) means "forward" and it used in exclamations like this.
Both [Tertullian](http://www.thelatinlibrary.com/tertullian/tertullian.valentinianos.shtml) and [Apuleius](http://www.thelatinlibrary.com/apuleius/apuleius8.shtml) use the phrase *porro quirites* as "forward, Romans"!

The name of the city seems to be used as both *Varsovia* and *Varsavia*.
Either one seems acceptable to me.

Comment: @Matt I'm glad to be able to help! I look forward to seeing more questions from you. If you have found the answer you're looking for, you can mark it as "accepted" by clicking the check mark next to it. But there's no hurry. After you get a little more reputation points, you'll be able to vote up all questions and answers you like.